# Local database for storing base64 images in quasar app

Tags: cordova, base64, local-storage, store, quasar

For my **quasar** (cordova based) app, i have some objects and images with base64 format needs to be stored in local for **offline** mode use.

I thought images with **base64** are heavy and their size is big.

**localstorage** and quasar’s **store** are not set to do so.

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 1):

You can give a shot to https://github.com/globules-io/MongOGX and use `OGX.Mongogx.APP_STORAGE` mode to save your base64s into a JSON document via  cordova-plugin-file

wiki : https://github.com/globules-io/MongOGX/wiki